# what is the most efficient way to find the first element greater than a given number in an array for multiple queries?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have an array of numbers. My goal is to **find the index of the first element** which is greater than some value k while going from starting index towards right.

For example, if array is A = [4 3 3 4 6 7 1] and k = 3 and starting index is 1 (0 based indexing) than the index of first number which is greater than k is 3.
Similarly, if k = 3 and starting index = 0, then the index of first element is 0.

Preprocessing is fine as I need to process multiple such queries for different values of k and starting indexes.

**[Update]** There could be some array update queries as well in between any "find first index" queries. For example, an update query of index=1 with value=2 would change A to [4 5 3 4 6 7 1]

Comment: It should be 3. Updated. Thanks

Comment: Do you know all queries before hand?

Comment: There will also be some array value updates in between multiple k value queries

Comment: I don't get it, what are array value updates? Can you update your question and give some examples? Different constraints and requirements lead to different optimal solutions, please be specific.

Comment: @PhamTrung Updated the description.

Comment: Do you know segment tree?

Comment: yes. I do. Could it be used here?

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know all queries before hand, there is an algorithm with time complexity O( m  log n) with m is the number of queries and n is the number of elements.

Iterating through the array backward from end to start, and maintaining a dequeue structure.

- At index `i`, we try to pop from the front of the dequeue all elements that is less than current value at index `i`. Then append index `i` to the dequeue. We can easily see that all values in the dequeue are arranged in ascending order.
- For all queries that start at index `i`, use binary search in the dequeue to find the first element that is greater than `k`

Pseudo-code:

```java
Dequeue<Integer> q = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    while(!q.isEmpty() && q.peek() <= data[i]){
         q.poll();
    }
    q.addFirst(i);
    for all query start at i {
         int st = 0;
         int ed = q.size();
         int re = -1;
         while(st <= ed){
             int mid = (st + ed)/2;
             if(data[q.get(mid)] > k){
                 re = q.get(mid); 
                 st = mid - 1;
             }else{
                 ed = mid + 1;
             }
         }
         print(re);
    }
}
```

As the array can be updated in real time, so we need to use [Segment Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) to keep track of the maximum element in each segment of the array.

- For each query, we need to use binary search to search for the minimum segment that has maximum value greater than k.
- Time complexity O(m log log n) with m is the number of queries and n is number of elements.

Pseudo-code:

```java
Build segment tree from input array

for each query {
   if update query{
       update tree
   }else{
       int startIndex = starting index for this query;
       int start = startIndex;
       int end = ending index;
       int re = -1;
       while(start <= end){
           int mid = (start + end)/2;
           //Getting the maximum value in segment [startIndex, mid]
           if(tree.maximumInSegment(startIndex, mid) > k){
                 re = mid;
                 end = mid - 1; 
           }else{
                 start = mid + 1;
           }
       }
       print re;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Segment Tree Approach:
for a given value x and a range a[l…r] find the smallest i in the range a[l…r], such that a[i] is greater than x.

This task can be solved using binary search over max prefix queries with the Segment Tree. However, this will lead to a O(log^2(n)) solution.

find the position by descending the tree: by moving each time to the left or the right, depending on the maximum value of the left child. Thus finding the answer in O(logn) time.

```
int get_first(int v, int lv, int rv, int l, int r, int x) {
if(lv > r || rv < l) return -1;
if(l <= lv && rv <= r) {
    if(t[v] <= x) return -1;
    while(lv != rv) {
        int mid = lv + (rv-lv)/2;
        if(t[2*v] > x) {
            v = 2*v;
            rv = mid;
        }else {
            v = 2*v+1;
            lv = mid+1;
        }
    }
    return lv;
}

int mid = lv + (rv-lv)/2;
int rs = get_first(2*v, lv, mid, l, r, x);
if(rs != -1) return rs;
return get_first(2*v+1, mid+1, rv, l ,r, x);
```

}

For More Clarifications on Segment Tree Check This Out:  [Segment Tree](https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/segment_tree.html)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on data and query it might actually be more efficient to do the naive approach. Go to the starting index, and then simply look for a value greater than k.

```py
array = [4, 3, 3, 4, 6, 7, 1]
# eliminate candidates based on starting_index
candidate_set = [3, 3, 4, 6, 7, 1]
# find index of first element greater than k in linear time
result = 2 + starting_index
```

You should probably try this first.

---

If you find that you could narrow down the candidate set quicker based on the value (vs. based on the starting_index), you can also try that approach:

```py
array = [4, 3, 3, 4, 6, 7, 1]
```

Preprocessing step: Have an index that produces the array index ordered by the sorted values. (If you update the array, you must now also update the index.)

```py
# first column value, second column array index
index = [(1, 6), (3, 1), (3, 2), (4, 0), (4, 3), (6, 4), (7, 5)]
```

Retrieve the list of array indices whose value is greater than k = 3 using array bisection or binary search.

```py
candidate_set = [(4, 0), (4, 3), (6, 4), (7, 5)]
```

Filter out candidates whose starting index is not greater than the starting index = 1.

```py
candidate_set = [(4, 3), (6, 4), (7, 5)]
```

Pick the smallest array index by iterating this list.

```py
result = 3
```

---

If you are in the mood to spend some memory to save CPU cycles later, you could add memoization or even precompute all the results for all possible queries to a lookup table. (And think about cache invalidation.)

Comment: Could you please explain abit more of the preprocessing step, may be with a small simple example. It's kind of not clear to me.

Comment: @user3243499 I've added some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm steps.

1. Map the array values to the indexes, map.put(A[0],array[values])
2. Sort the keys with a Set of unique values/ Array values (in example Array A )
3. Binary search the key for value greater than K
4. get the Indexes from map as mapIndex[] = map.get(value > k)
5. find Index such that mapIndex[i] >= StartingIndex